# How to find and extract parts of a string in a Pandas column and encode it into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column like this:

| Id | language |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Spanish - C1 |
| 02 | No |
| 03 | Spanish - B2 |
| 04 | Spanish - C1 / German - C1 / Portuguese - C1 |
| 05 | No |
| 06 | German C2 |
| 07 | No |
| 08 | Spanish - B2 / Portuguese - C1 |

Each id can have no language ('No'), it can have a single language followed by its level (eg 'Spanish - B2') or it can have several languages with their level separated by the "/" symbol (eg. "Italian-B1 / Portuguese-C2").

The idea is to encode in new columns with the information from the 'language' column. For example, something like this:

| id | no_lang | Spanish - B2 | Spanish - C1 | German - C1 | German - C2 | Portuguese - C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 04 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 05 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 06 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 07 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 08 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

If there are multiple languages, they always appear in alphabetical order.

I imagine this is complex and I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df['language'] = df['language'].str.split(' / ')
df = df.explode('language')
pd.crosstab(index=df['Id'], columns=df['language'])
```

Output:

```
language  German - C1  German C2  No  Portuguese - C1  Spanish - B2  \
Id                                                                    
1                   0          0   0                0             0   
2                   0          0   1                0             0   
3                   0          0   0                0             1   
4                   1          0   0                1             0   
5                   0          0   1                0             0   
6                   0          1   0                0             0   
7                   0          0   1                0             0   
8                   0          0   0                1             1   

language  Spanish - C1  
Id                      
1                    1  
2                    0  
3                    0  
4                    1  
5                    0  
6                    0  
7                    0  
8                    0
```